# PHP Web Counter

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a web counter, that count number who visit my website.

I use a txtfile as a counter, however when I start loading my web there was an error encounter.

Message: file_put_contents() [function.file-put-contents]: Filename cannot be empty

```
<?php if(! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller{


    function _construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function index(){

//Function Web Counter (count visitor)
$filename = 'counterePOD.txt';
function  inc_count() {
    global $filename;

    if (file_exists($filename)){
        $current_value = file_get_contents($filename);
    }else{
        $current_value = 0;
    }

    file_put_contents($filename, ++$current_value);
}

inc_count();
    }
    $this->load->view('login_view');    
    }
}
?>
```

Somebody can tell what is the exact meaning of the error msg: "Filename cannot be empty"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a more OOP approach and pass the filename to the inc_count function:

```
<?php if(! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller{


    function _construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function  inc_count($filename) {

        if (file_exists($filename)){
            $current_value = file_get_contents($filename);
        }else{
            $current_value = 0;
        }

        file_put_contents($filename, ++$current_value);
    }

    function index(){
        //Function Web Counter (count visitor)
        $this->inc_count('counterePOD.txt');
        $this->load->view('login_view');    
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: check for writing permissions on that file

Comment: sorry, but how to check that permissions?

Comment: depends on your server location and ftp client you are using. if you are running localhost on linux write in your terminal: chmod 777 counterePOD.txt . If you are using a software like Filezilla to transer files on your server, right click -> properties on that file and check the permissions fields.

Comment: I'm using localhost on windows

Comment: Right click on the file -> Properties -> Security tab and check for write permissions in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the filename as an argument of the function like this. using global variable is not a good practice..

```
//Function definition
function  inc_count($filename) {
    if (file_exists($filename)){
        $current_value = file_get_contents($filename);
    }else{
        $current_value = 0;
    }

    file_put_contents($filename, ++$current_value);
}

//Function call
$filename = 'counterePOD.txt';
inc_count($filename);
```

Comment: Message: Missing argument 1 for inc_count(),

Comment: Thats because you have'nt passed the argument during function call.Check my updated anser

Comment: That may be because of your file operations.Check whther you have to give permisions for the file.

Comment: sorry, but how to check that permissions??